# searching information within files

Tags: windows-7, search, file-search

I need some information which is stored with in a file on Windows 7 system,
I do not remember the file name rather what I remember is a bit of keywords which are stored some where in some file.How can I search in this scenario?

Comment: You might want to check out these previous SuperUser Q&As on content searching: http://superuser.com/questions/66699/best-windows-software-to-search-file-content http://superuser.com/questions/9628/silly-full-text-search

Comment: thanks you people are right agent ran sack is what I should be having